# Composer: lib (React PHP) only partially autoloading

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, autoloader, reactphp

One component in the React lib is auto-loading, but the majority are not.

I Composed react/react into my project, and everything in that process went smoothly.
Upon trying to use `React\EventLoop\Factory` or `React\Stream\Stream`, a "class not found" error is thrown.
I switched on xDebug and noticed that the `Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->prefixes['R']` array includes `React\Promise` ... but ***nothing*** else.
It *seems* to me that other React libs should be in there, too.

Seeing that, I var_dumped `\React\Promise\any('string')` and it successfully autoloaded the `React\Promise` namespace.
Still, the classes under the other `React\` namespaces fail to autoload.
I can't help but suspect that my problem is in some related way to their distinct absence from the `Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->prefixes` array, but being fairly novice, that's just a hunch.

BTW, just to make sure everything was at least accessible, I ***did*** try hard-coded `require`'s on those classes.  It succeeded (other than the subsequent dependencies not being autoloaded, of course :)

What do you suspect could be causing this type of *kinda/kinda-not* autoloading?

Comment: Have you tried to generate the autoloader again? Try `composer -o dump-autoload`.

Comment: Haven't, thanks. I will, and I'll post back.  .. Oh!, BTW, I forgot to mention that, while exploring. I _did_ look at `installed.json`, and it does show the `react/react` lib in there. I'll try your suggestion regardless, and post back.

Comment: Yay!! it works. Thanks @DiegoAgulló. The project got shelved for a bit. I just got back into it today and wanted to post back here to say thanks.